# How to check what value array holds?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am writting a chess game using mostly JavaScript and now that I have defined how a certain chess piece can move I have encountered a problem. How do I write a code that checks if a figure is in its way and if that figure is black or white.

I am using a  with , each one with a unique data-row and data-column. The pieces are stored in a two dimensional array that holds their initial position. `aPosit[[1,1]]="&#9814"` `*White Fortress*`. Each `<td>` also has an `onclick` function (that reads its id and stores it in a variable `elemId1`) and an `onwheel` function that copies its initial value onto the `"wheeled"` `<td>`

Perhaps something with an `if( document.getElementById(elemId2).lastChild.nodeValue != (array[[*a white piece*]])`? How do I check whether or not the `<td>` holds a piece and if so, what piece does it hold?

here is a piece of code (it looks really messy for the moment) - the first if statement declares that the KING may only move for one field in each direction

```
case "♔":
                        {
                            if((((document.getElementById(elemId2).dataset.row*1 - document.getElementById(elemId1).dataset.row*1)*(document.getElementById(elemId2).dataset.row*1 - document.getElementById(elemId1).dataset.row*1))==1) || (((document.getElementById(elemId2).dataset.column*1 - document.getElementById(elemId1).dataset.column*1)*(document.getElementById(elemId2).dataset.column*1 - document.getElementById(elemId1).dataset.column*1))==1))
                            {
                                elemId2=element.id;
                                document.getElementById(elemId2).innerHTML = sel1;
                                document.getElementById(elemId1).innerHTML = " ";
                                o1++;   
                            }
                        }
                        break;
```

Comment: Post code here please.

Comment: Shouldn;t you always have a full chessboard in memory that you can reference check?